# Dynamically increasing the ionic list item height with embedded textarea content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I have included a textarea in ionic list. Please help me out to achieve the following requirement

1. Textarea height should be increased with the content height
2. The height of the list item should also be increased according to textarea height
3. List item height should remain same even after scrolling.

Here is the code snippet I am using

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <textarea placeholder="Address"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at CSS source, make custom class, remove paddings, margins in that class and attach to that .item class, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular Elastic solved my issue. Here is the link
[Angular Elastic](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-elastic). May be useful to someone.